# Best DSL hardware for ADSL Troubleshooting

Tags: linux, wide-area-network, dsl

I have a situation where I need to make the best of a bad DSL situation. The CPE is a black box with no access to DSL diagnostics. My plan is to get some sort of DSL hardware that exposes link-layer state and gives me knobs to tweak. I'd like to be able to mitigate bufferbloat as much as I can while I'm at it. The obvious choice would seem to be a Sangoma card in a linux system. I have no way of knowing if that will do anything for me without testing it, however. I have no other access to WAN troubleshooting equipment. Are there any other options avail to me as a consumer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd either go with the Sangoma ADSL card, or possibly just bridge to PPPoE with a Draytek Vigor 120, and then handle the rest of the handshake nonsense on a better device, by just terminating the PPP stuff on your router/server.

Other than that, there's not a great deal of options.  There are some [ADSL2+ cards for Cisco ISR routers](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps10536/data_sheet_c78-644629.html).

Other than that, you might be SOL, I'm afraid.